# is it possible to give a rig on non-solid object?

Tags: rigging

I want to give some rig on my soda can ring and cap for animation purpose. since my model didn't use solid mesh, idk it could be works or not.

[image]

[image]

i want to move this part
[image]

into this one, with rig of course
[image]

after i use set parent from rig into my mesh, it didn't made any movement.

Comment: Of course you can, what kind of animation are you trying to achieve exactly? It will all depend on that...

Comment: for the first, idk how armature joints work. i just knew if i can move around my mesh without split my mesh with this. for the second, there is no reference on youtube where we can move some mesh with non-solid mesh.

Comment: if you open my blend file, you can look if my bottom part of my model doesn't have rim or mesh on there.

@moonboots. I just want to open and close my soda can caps and ring with rig

Comment: just create an armature, with one bone by part that needs to move, and parent the parts to the bones. If some parts need to be flexible, you need to create chains of bone and maybe segment each bone. If you show a storyboard it would help to understand the animation

Comment: it solved, thanks for your help everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to armature deform any mesh, regardless of whether that mesh is solid (watertight, manifold) or not.

Automatic weights will not necessarily work well for meshes that are non-manifold.  But that's not the only way to create weights.  Here, we would want to use weight painting or assignment to create the bone weights.  So rather than using parent->armature deform with automatic weights, we would use parent->armature deform with empty groups, and then edit the vertex groups.

In the file, you've started making bones.  You have more bones than you need to achieve the deformation you're demonstrating in your picture.  Each object bends only around a single origin, so for each object, we need only one bone for the base object and one bone for the bendy bit:

[image]

Notice the weight painting.  I've assigned some vertices entirely to Bone and some vertices entirely to Bone.001.